# Automapper deep mappings ignoring null members

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper

I am trying to use Automapper to accomplish mappings between my ViewModels and POCOs.
I have a view that shows Questions on the page, showing the `Text` and a checkbox - setting the `Selected` property.
this is posted back and the controller maps it back over the top of the existing Application data. as the Text is not posted back, I do not want to wipe this out, so have attempted to ignore the Text mapping when the ViewModel value is null. but it is not working. When I try a test using simply the Question and QuestionViewModel - the mapping works fine as shown below.

I have the following

```
public class Question{
  public string Text {get;set;}
  public bool Selected {get;set;}
}
public class QuestionViewModel{
  public string Text{get;set;}
  public bool Selected {get;set;}
}
and the mapping I have setup like this:
CreateMap<Question, QuestionViewModel>();
CreateMap<QuestionViewModel, Question>().
  .ForMember(q => q.Selected, opt => opt.MapFrom(vm => vm.Selected))
  .ForMember(q => q.Text, opt => opt.Condition((s, d, m) => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m)));
```

this I have tested successfully and is all good

```
Mapper.Map(questionViewModelInstance, questionInstance);
```

this correctly sets the Selected on the questionInstance without overwriting the Text, which is null in the questionViewModel.

However, when I have these Question types as children of other classes, things dont go so well

```
public class QuestionsViewModel{
  public IList<QuestionViewModel> Questions{get;set;}
}
public class Application{
  public Product Product {get;set;}
..other properties omitted
}
public class Product{
  public IList<Question> Questions {get;set;}
..other properties omitted
}
```

and the mappings - used along with the ones above

```
CreateMap<Application, QuestionsViewModel>()
  .ForMember(qvm=>qvm.Questions, opt=>opt.MapFrom(a=>a.Product.Questions));
CreateMap<QuestionsViewModel, Application>()
  .ForMember(a=>a.Product, opt=>opt.MapFrom(qvm=>qvm));
CreateMap<QuestionsViewModel, Product>();
CreateMap<Product, QuestionsViewModel>();
```

trying instead with identical Questions/QuestionViewModel data as above

```
Mapper.Map(questionsViewModel, application)
```

incorrectly wipes the Text property on the Application.Product.Questions.

what I am missing/doing wrong here?
any help very much appreciatead

Comment: Would it be possible for you to generate a small sample program (console app) with inputs - that you can provide the source code for, so we can get up and running fast to diagnose and fix it?

Comment: this is the minimum that explains the problem.. what should I omit?

Comment: I can simply paste in my tests and classes somewhere if that would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destination collections are cleared first. Probably a duplicate of [Automapper, updating an object with a child list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278651/automapper-updating-an-object-with-a-child-list-of-objects/45300623#45300623).

Comment: that automapper extension appears to allow deletion, replacement or addition based on a rule on the list item type, but not update an existing one based on a mapping rule..

Comment: I think it does what you want.